# QGIS 3.22 - Oracle- how to connect to db w/o host?

Tags: qgis

when I fill in all nessessary fields like database, username, password I can successful test the connection, but the OK- Button stays disabled. If I fill in a host (no matter, whether the correct host or any blanks) the ok- button is enabled, but neither the test connect works, nor the connection is useable.

What can I do to connect?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. This sounds rather vague and not really programming related. [gis.se] might be better suited for questions about GIS.

Comment: Thanks. I did not knew this page. My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. If I deleted the Port- Entry (what was automatically filled by qgis) the button is enabled.